# How do I block with specific string with IPTABLES?

Tags: linux, iptables

Want to block this URL STRING with IPTABLES. Need to know specific command.

```
"GET /affiliate/5/campaigns?api_key=duO5gVw3s0&affiliate_id=67647&format=json HTTP/1.0" 404 785 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; XT1032 Build/KXB21.14-L1.40)"
```

Want to use this to block it. I just want to block the URL path. Its not working though any tips?

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "GET /affiliate/5/campaigns?api_key=duO5gVw3s0&affiliate_id=67647&format=json" -j DROP
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab108.1/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

Comment: That should work.  Is this request definitely over http and not https?

Comment: Its HTTP. I am seeing this [root@host logs]# iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "GET /affiliate/5/campaigns?api_key=duO5gVw3s0&affiliate_id=67647&format=json" -j DROP
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab108.1/modules.dep: No such file or directory

Comment: I would check the packet contents with wireshark and check `iptables -L` and make sure the strings match exactly.  If they do, then consider starting with a shorter string to make sure the principle works, then extending it to see where it stops working.  Also make sure there isn't an earlier rule in iptables that is permitting the traffic and bypassing this rule.

Comment: Ah.  That error means my previous comment doesn't help

Comment: Is there another line after the FATAL  error?  It should tell us what is missing - check `dmesg` if not.

Comment: There is no other fatal error. Do I check dmesg like this vim /var/log/dmesg? According to the iptables -l output it looks like it should drop the request.

Comment: The `modules.dep` strongly hints that your kernel doesn't have any string match functionality built, or that something about loading kernel modules is broken.  BTW you may be better off using a http proxy for URL filtering.

Comment: The system is using plesk 12 is there a good HTTP PROXY app for it for URL filtering?

Comment: just the command `dmesg` will show the dmesg, and should highlight what module is missing.  You might just need to `insmod` the filter module.  Is this request incoming or outgoing?

Comment: The request is incoming

Comment: how do I insmod the filter module dmesg is not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message, you miss the `modules.dep` file, which prevents the automatic loading of the `xt_string` module. You can try to remedy this by running `depmod -a`; if that fails too, then you're likely missing the modules for your current kernel version, so you should install them. You can also try inserting the module manually, by running `insmod /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab108.1/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_string.ko`.